# Sync application data between several devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, synchronization

I've got 3 devices and 1 application.
I make some changes on 1 device (collect milk from my cows). What is the best way server to tell other applications, that I've made this changes to reload data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the integrated iCloud feature allowing [synchronization for CoreData managed objects](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/releasenotes/DataManagement/RN-iCloudCoreData/index.html). There are also some libraries using third party Cloud services like https://github.com/nothirst/TICoreDataSync

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications could be an option. Once your server receives some changes it will issue the sync notification to all other devices which will initiate the sync.

Another option is where every device will periodically check, let’s say every 5 minutes, if any server changes available, and if so, then initiate the sync.